# How to use orderCollectionFactory and productCollectionFactory together in Model file?

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection, custom-attributes, order-collection

I have created a custom attribute in product and saved a string in that value and I want if some one order those product of same value string i want that collection of product.
So, i want to use

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
```

these together is there a way to get these product.

Comment: check this link - ordercollectionfactory use - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160609/85907

Comment: Thanks for the response but i am Getting this error
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'custom_field' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (`custom_field` = 'testfield') @MohitPatel

Comment: Actually i want to use order and product collection togather @Mohit

Comment: You can use two class together

Comment: can you suggest me any example for that it will help @Amit

Comment: will you please help me with this question also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319422/how-to-solve-401-redirect-on-rest-api-on-custom-tab-between-shipping-and-payment it will be really helpful @AmitBera

Answer (score 0):

I hope it would be helpful for you. In below code I have used orderCollectionFactory to retrieve custom attribute value:

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollection;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;

class YOURClass 
{
    /**
     * @var orderCollection
     */  
    private $orderCollection;
    /**
     * @var ProductCollection
     */
    private $productCollection;
    /**
     * @var logger
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $orderCollection,
        ProductCollection $productCollection,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->orderCollection = $orderCollection;
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->orderCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', '000000003');

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $order) {
            foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $this->logger->log('600', print_r($item->getProduct()->getData('custom_field'), true));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will implement this will you please help me with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319422/how-to-solve-401-redirect-on-rest-api-on-custom-tab-between-shipping-and-payment?noredirect=1#comment457831_319422 this question @Bushra

Comment: Please share the saveSimpleNote method implementation for the above query.

Comment: Updated my code please check tell me anything needed @Bushra

Comment: Did the above code work for you?

Comment: It works only for loggedin user not for guest user if you are talking about this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319422/how-to-solve-401-redirect-on-rest-api-on-custom-tab-between-shipping-and-payment?noredirect=1#comment457831_319422

I have done some other way around for this question.@Bushra